# How to insert into table using laravel raw query as well as parameters?

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
DB::table('my_table')->insertGetId([
    ...
    'code' => $data['code'],
    'geopoint' => \DB::raw('POINT(?, ?)', [$data['lat'], $data['lng']]),
    ...
]);
```

it returns

```
Invalid parameter number (SQL: insert into `residence` (`code`, values (POINT(, ), , ?, ?)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: try  `'geopoint' => \DB::raw('POINT(:lat, :lng)', [ 'lat' => $data['lat'], 'lng' => $data['lng'] ]),`

Comment: @rkj now it returns `Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: insert into `my_table` (`code`, `geopoint`) values (123456, POINT(:lat, :lng), , , ,))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

create array for the value you want to insert apply key same as field name in you table

```
$point = DB::select("SELECT POINT($data['lat'], $data['lng']) as point FROM `any_table_name_avilable_in_your_db` LIMIT 1"); 

$data=array(
    "lat_field_name_table"=>$data['lat'],
    "lng_field_name_table"=>$data['lng'],
    "location"=>$point[0]->point
);

$checkinsert=DB::table('mytablename')->insert($data);
```

and check is your data inserted like this

```
if($checkinsert>0){
    //data inserted 
   //do whatever you want if inserted
}else{
   //data not inserted 
   //do whatever you want if not inserted
}
```

or in your way like this :

```
$point = DB::select("SELECT POINT($data['lat'], $data['lng']) as point FROM any_table_name_avilable_in_your_db LIMIT 1"); 

DB::table('my_table')->insertGetId([ 
... 
'code' => $data['code'], 
'geopoint' =>$point[0]->point , 
... 
]);
```

Comment: What about SQLInjection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670933/prevent-sql-injection-for-queries-that-combine-the-query-builder-with-dbraw

Comment: No I mean how I can prevent it in this query. It doesn't bind `$data['lat']` to `lat_field_name_table`, does it?

Comment: if its single array containing key as field name and value then it will bind if you pass two diffrant array one for field and another for value then it will not bind. see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805429/binding-parameters-in-laravel-insert-query

Comment: How can I set point for it when it needs POINT function in mysql? it is not single value to set to its related column. it should bind to that query and calculate then put it in that column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176924/discussion-between-kodfire-and-developer-kt).

Comment: This is not injection save. You could as good just insert `'geopoint' => DB::raw("POINT({$data['lat']}, {$data['lng']})")`